# Can we integrate gstreamer in electron application?How?

Tags: html, electron, gstreamer, desktop-application, rtsp

I am doing java-script based desktop application. The problem is, i have to stream rtsp videos. is it possible to use g-streamer plugin with electron? or is some other plugin available rtsp for desktop application?

I am completely new to the streaming rtsp concept and desktop application.

Answer (score 6):

I did such project some time ago: https://github.com/RSATom/wcjs-gs and it worked well. But don't sure if it still works with latest Electron version.
Soon I plan back to it and update to support latest Electron/NW.js/Node.js versions.

Upd: I don't plan keep compatibility with Electron or NW.js anymore. Sorry.

Comment: @RSTAtom Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /app/available_modules/1527996618000/wcjs-gs/build/wcjs-gs.node
 → /app/available_modules/1527996618000

Comment: tbh I didn't try it long time, it seems it's broken atm. I think will fix it within month or so...

Comment: Ported it to N-Api. Now it's compatible with latest Electron.

Comment: How can i port it?.If it port it to means let it play rtsp video from the webserver.

Comment: No, ported - is just updated for new API used by Electon/Node.js atm.
What about rtsp - I'll prepare demo with rtsp source soon (I hope, I'm a little bit limited in free time)

Comment: @PMO1948 It's already happened. Did you try latest versions?